# GCG compiling error within the Scipoptsuite-6.0.0: reader_zpl.c:(.text+0x319): undefined reference to `zpl_read'

Tags: makefile, scip

I already downloaded Scipoptsuite-6.0.0 and installed scip by the command 'make' 'make install' in the main directory of the Scipoptsuite-6.0.0. Then I compiled the GCG through the command 'make gcg' in the same directory, and errors related to 'reader_zpl.c' happen:

```
-> linking bin/gcg-3.0.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx2
/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/scip/lib/static/libscip.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a(reader_zpl.o): In function `readerReadZpl':
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0x319): undefined reference to `zpl_read'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0x61b): undefined reference to `zpl_read_with_args'
/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/scip/lib/static/libscip.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a(reader_zpl.o): In function `xlp_addcon_term':
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xb3e): undefined reference to `numb_todbl'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xb51): undefined reference to `numb_todbl'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xbb3): undefined reference to `term_is_linear'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xc94): undefined reference to `mono_get_coeff'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xc9c): undefined reference to `numb_todbl'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xccb): undefined reference to `term_get_elements'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xcdd): undefined reference to `term_get_element'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xcea): undefined reference to `mono_get_var'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xcf5): undefined reference to `mono_get_function'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xd07): undefined reference to `mono_get_var'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0xd8c): undefined reference to `term_get_degree'
```

and following a lot of same kind of errors:

```
/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/scip/lib/static/libscip.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a(reader_zpl.o): In function `xlp_getlower':
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0x320c): undefined reference to `bound_new'
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0x323e): undefined reference to `bound_new'

    /home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/scip/lib/static/libscip.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a(reader_zpl.o): In function `xlp_addtocost':
reader_zpl.c:(.text+0x33e9): undefined reference to `numb_todbl'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:547: recipe for target 'bin/gcg-3.0.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx2' failed
make[4]: *** [bin/gcg-3.0.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx2] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg'
Makefile:402: recipe for target 'mainfiles' failed
make[3]: [mainfiles] Error 2 (ignored)
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg'

** Build complete.
** Find your GCG binary in "/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg/bin".
```

And after the compilation, I cannot find the GCG binary. These errors appear again when I tried to compile GCG in the 'scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg' sub-directory. How should I do to fix these errors in order to run gcg?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion about whether ZIMPL is around or not.
Try doing the first build with ZIMPL=false (as argument to the call of make) or the one of GCG with ZIMPL=true.

Comment: Now I set 'make ZIMPL=false gcg' in the 'scipoptsuite-6.0.0' directory, and it really works without an error: ** Find your GCG binary in "/home/yang/Documents/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg/bin".  I can find the share library document of 'gcg-3.0.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx2' in the folder ''scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg/bin'. Then, how can I install the gcg? Should I do 'make install gcg' in the scipoptsuite-6.0.0 folder? or in the scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg folder?

Comment: I enter the './gcg' in the ''scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg/bin' direcotry and started the GCG software. I am not sure if this is the right way to run gcg because after installation of SCIP I could start it just by typing 'scip' in the command window in any directory.

Comment: I never tried installing gcg, but 'make install ZIMPL=false' in the gcg subdirectory might work. But running gcg from 'scipoptsuite-6.0.0/gcg/bin' isn't particularly bad either.